# Retrieve and display Active Record data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to show a number of things on my homepage, all being pulled from different tables in the database and just wanted to see the best way to do it.

Reading through https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/active_record_querying.html, I was able to get it to show the correct details, but is this the best way to do it? Are there performance issues to come with this method?

```
<% about = Page.find(1) %>
<h1 class="title"><%= about.title %></h1>
<% unless about.subtitle.blank? %>
    <h2 class="subtitle"><%= about.subtitle %></h2>
<% end %>
<p><%= about.body %></p>
```

And on a similar topic, what is the best way to iterate and display data? This is what I would like to achieve:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <% Chapter.all.each do |c| %>
            <li><a><%= chapter.title %></a></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any tips greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're reading guides for a really old version of Rails - I don't think you're using that version. Make sure you're reading the right guides.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <% Chapter.all.each do |c| %>
            <li><a><%= c.title %></a></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

There is a few things that must be present:

> First step

You need to have a model or data set that represent your data, example you might have a Person.rb file with name and hair color as properties. That can be your model, all it is doing is defining a dataset.

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
    scope :latest_Person, -> { order(date: :desc) }

    validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
    validates :haircolor, presence: true
end
```

> Second step

You need to declare or instantiate that model in your controller class, example you might need to show a list of persons in a particular order. That can be handled using `scopes`. Example

```
def persons
   # Render all persons
   @persons_all = Person.latest_Person
end
```

> Third step

Calling the declared object from the controller class in the view. Basically all you are doing is referencing the declared object. Example

```
<% if @persons_all.empty? %>
  <h2>No persons available</h2>
<% else %>
   <% @persons_all.each do |p| %>
      <p><%= p.name %></p>
      <p><%= p.haircolor %></p>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Mark as answer is it helped, thank you.

Comment: Thanks! That went somewhat over my head, but I appreciate the thorough reply.

This is my chapter.rb file
`class Chapter < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :chapter_members
    has_many :users, through: :chapter_members
end`

And chapters_controller.rb just has this (I have edit etc in an admin namespace.)

`def index
        @chapters = Chapter.all
    end`

Is the scoping that you mentioned on top of that?

Comment: Scoping can be handled in the class and called in the controller. Also please note i only used `scopes` because i wanted to get a list of Persons who were created first etc and order them based on that.

Comment: Late reply, but I finally had time to try and implement your code from above, but I just get `undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Did you create the class that will be called in your controller?

Comment: Yep, I have

`def chapters
    @all_chapters = Chapter.chapter_list
 end`

and

`<% if @all_chapters.empty? %>
     <h2>No chapters available</h2>
<% else %>
    <% @all_chapters.each do |c| %>
         <p><%= c.name %></p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>`

Comment: can you post the Model class?

Comment: Sure, thanks for your help on this.

`class Chapter < ApplicationRecord
    scope :chapter_list, -> { order(date: :desc) }
end`

Comment: The line `scope :chapter_list, -> { order(date: :desc) }` in your class is referencing a property date that is missing from your class. The reason why i used the order by scope is to show you if you have a list of items and you want to show them by date you can do it that way.

If you dont have a date property in your class you could remove the scope declaration all together and just have a class with properties in it

Comment: Sadly it's all a bit over my head at this point. Thanks for your help all the same.